# How to add specific values in a column (SQL)

Tags: sql

the table is like this

```
Product_Group      value
a                   100
a                    50
b                    50
b                    50
b                   100
c                   200
```

and I need to create a new column and at the same time take out the redundancy in Product_Group, so the result should be

```
Product_group      Sum
a                   150
b                   200
c                   200
```

Cheers!

Comment: do you actually need to remove the records permanently and update permanently or just show the results in a select? also what version of sql are you using? (sql-server, oracle, mysql?)

Comment: what is your database? SQL Server or MYSql or else?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Group BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) Clause. However, this is not a good idea to use reseverd keyword `SUM` as a column name, but if you want to wrap in bracekts.

```
SELECT Product_group, SUM(Value) as [SUM]
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Product_group
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Query in MySQL

```
 SELECT Product_group, SUM(Value) "SUM"
 FROM tablename
 GROUP BY Product_group
```